# JQuery AJAX fails before making the request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is what I'm doing:

```
$.ajax({
    "url":"localhost:8888/check_app",
    "success":function(data) {
        alert("success!");
        callback(data);
    },
    "error":function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Which errors out on both FF and Chrome. Firebug shows that no XHR request was made.

---

Edit: I use node.js on the backend; and the console shows it did not receive any requests.

When I change $.ajax to $.get, I do see a XHR request in Firebug, but the url is some weird encoded string I do not recognize.

I've been working on this whole afternoon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, your browser is looking for a folder named `localhost:8888` and a file in that folder called `check_app`.

What you want is to make the path absolute, with `http://localhost:8888/check_app` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, the object keys don't have quotes around them - it should be url : not "url" :

You may also need to place an http:// in front of the URL for $.ajax where as it may not be required for $.get...strange behavior, but possible I suppose.

Comment: Those quotes are perfectly valid. It's called JSON.

Comment: Object keys can have quotes around them.

Comment: Corbin is correct.  var foo = { "bar": 5 } creates a valid javascript object.